# Получение всех значений из связанной таблицы (многие-ко-многим)

Tags: laravel

Есть три таблицы: `users` (с полями **id** и **login**), `roles` (с полями **id**, **name** и **slug**) и третья для связи `role_user` (с полями **role_id** и **user_id**). Как получить все значения из связанной таблицы?

В файле модели `User` прописана связь:

```
public function roles()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

В файле модели `Role` прописана связь:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'role_user', 'role_id', 'user_id');
}
```

В файле `UserController` пытаюсь получить значения:

```
$users = User::with('roles')->get();

dump($users->roles);
```

В итоге получаю **ошибку**:

```
Property [roles] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

p.s. Получение по **id** значения через `find(id)` работает. Пробовал получить значения через `$user->pivot`, но в результате та же ошибка, только для `pivot`. Аналогичная ошибка в `RoleController`. Почему я получаю эту ошибку и как получить все значения для связанной таблицы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная `$users` уже хранит коллекции модели `User`. Ошибка возникает из-за попытки получить свойство `roles` у всей коллекции `roles`. В данном примере, получить все роли для каждого пользователя можно так:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
  foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    dump($role->slug)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $users = User::with('roles')->get();
   foreach($users as $user){
       dump($user->roles);
    }
```

$user возвращают array для того там нету roles